# Solr: How to store data in lower case for specific field while importing by CSV?

Tags: solr

I have fields in `schema.xml` as below

```
<field name="Colour" type="string"/>
<field name="MerchantCampaignName" multiValued="false" type="string" indexed="true"/>
<field name="Name" type="text_general" indexed="true"/>
<field name="SKU" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="Size" type="string" indexed="true"/>
```

So while importing data from CSV, in the color field there are values like `"red", "Red", "Reds"`.

In facet query on `"Colour"` field, it treated all three values as different.

SO is there any setting to save `"Colour"` field as lower case and also for singular and plural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `KeywordTokenizerFactory` and `LowerCaseFilterFactory` for the same. You have create a custom field type using the above and apply the same to your field.

The `keywordTokenizer` is : This tokenizer treats the entire text field as a single token.

You can use the below field type for your field. The advantage would be it would help to search for words in all the case...UPPER and LOWER case both.

```
<fieldType name="lowercaseExactMatch" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here is your field defination would be :

```
<field name="Colour" type="lowercaseExactMatch" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: ok so while saving, It stored data as it is but when we query with facet then it displays in lower case

Comment: is it the case?...I think it should store in the original from...indexes are created in lowercase...

Comment: Also can we change plural words to singular?