# SOLR: fq query is not working with custom field

Tags: solr

I have implemented the filter from this url as it is given in answer

[Solr: How to store data in lower case for specific field while importing by CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298911/solr-how-to-store-data-in-lower-case-for-specific-field-while-importing-by-csv)

```
<fieldType name="lowercaseExactMatch" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This work perfect with one word colour in this query

```
"fq":"Colour:red"
```

but when i search for **Colour:light sky blue** it shows me 0 results. Records for Light sky blue are available but not listed while search.

Comment: Try this if already not tried. fq=Colour:"light sky blue"

Comment: @raghu777 Tried but it's not working

Comment: Can you confirm if there is a document with the value "light sky blue" in exactly this phrase?

Comment: its like "Colour":"Light Sky Blue" in document. But if you check question we used LowerCaseFilterFactory

Comment: In the Solr dashboard in the analysis section under the selected collection. Select field type as lowercaseExactMatch,  put Light Sky Blue in the index, and put light sky blue in query section and click run Analyse Values. Share the resultant screenshot.

Comment: not found lowercaseExactMatch option. There is lowercase option i used. please check below link for screenshot https://i.paste.pics/7b1e68fb0ca1f30b032e8531a4e3ce15.png

Comment: after adding the above schema changes have you reloaded the collection/restarted Solr and reindexed content?

Comment: yes. restarted solr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213067/discussion-between-raghu777-and-deepali).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the solution which is work for me.

When we are using **KeywordTokenizerFactory** we need to add \ prefix to space which will give us proper result.

```
"fq":"Colour:light\ sky\ blue"
```